# create UIImageView

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch, uiimageview

How do I create a `UIImageView` in code, instead of creating it in my xib file?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
UIImageView *someImageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:someRect];
someImageView.image = someImage;
[self.view addSubview:someImageView];
```

Easy as pie! :D

You might wanna check the apple docs too:
http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIImageView_Class/Reference/Reference.html

Comment: should this be `UIImageView *someImageView` and `someImageView.image = someImage;` ?

Comment: well i be damned. Yes it should've xD copying code and adjusting to general snippets seems to be hard xD

Answer (score 21):

You can create seperately a UIImage, and create your UIImageView from your UIImage.

```
UIImage *myImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"great_pic.png"];
UIImageView *myImageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:myImage];
```

Then, set the size of your UIImageView

```
[myImageView setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 100, 200)];
```

Do whatever you want with your image, but don't forget to release it.

```
[anotherView addSubview:myImageView];
[myImageView release];
```

Comment: If developing in Xcode 4.2 with ARC (Automatic Reference Counting) enabled, you do not need to (indeed, you must not) do [myImageView release]; as ARC handles the release of objects for you.

Answer (score 5):

The answers so far are more complex than they need to be: initWithImage: “adjusts the frame of the receiver to match the size of the specified image.” So all you need is

```
UIImageView* v = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage: someImage];
```

Answer (score 3):

```
UIImageView *imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(100, 7, 190, 23];
tabNameBackGround.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"a.png"];
[self.view addSubview:imageView];
```